# Pass different variables into a template function

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function that assigns 2 variables some values:
`bool get(int& value1, string& value2);`

I need to call a template function with one of these returned variables. How do I do this exactly?

```
bool get(int& value1, string& value2) { /* assign them */ };

template<typename T>
doWork(const T& value) { /* do some work */ };

template<typename T>
void foo() {
  int value1;
  string value2;
  get(value1, value2);
  while(doWork(/*if T == int, pass value1, otherwise value2*/)) {
    // do smth
  }
};
```

Comment: The only solution I came up with is to add 2 more get() function, with 3 params `get(int&, int&, string&` and `get(string&, int&, string&)`. So this way I'd just do smth like: `T value; get(value, value1, value2); doWork(value)` but I hope there's a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `if constexpr` (since C++17) together with `std::is_same` (from `<type_traits>`). As you want to use it inside the loop condition, I wrapped it in a lambda:

```
template<typename T>
void foo() {
  int value1;
  string value2;
  get(value1, value2);
  auto doWorkIntOrString = [&](){
      if constexpr (std::is_same_v<int,T>) return doWork(value1);
      else return doWork(value2);
  };
  while(doWorkIntOrString()) {
    // do smth
  }
};
```

Comment: I'll have to call this lambda over 100M times, unfortunately. My solution with a function with 3 arguments isn't perfect as well. Except overloading (or any functional object including lambda), do you know a solution that wouldn't require additional resources? Something, that would be done on compile time?

Comment: @vamirio-chan I don't understand what you are worried about. What "additional resources" ? The lambda is a prime candidate to be inlined, eg no penalty at all

Comment: @vamirio-chan you could "manually inline" it, the only reason I added the lambda is that you are using it inside the while condition and I didnt want to add the exact same two lines once before the loop and once inside the loop. It wouldnt be necessary for example if it was a `do-while` loop.

Comment: I didn't notice the cosntexpr there and assumed it'd have to execute is_same<> as many times as while runs. Thanks!

Comment: @vamirio-chan `is_same` is not executed. Its a type trait, which doesnt do anything at runtime